# Is there a way to use GWT.create(...) to instantiate a class of a generic type?

Tags: java, gwt, binding, deferred

Is there a way I can do something like this:

```
public class Foo<Bar> {
    public Bar newBar() {
        return GWT.create( /* something useful here */ );
    }
}
```

Would this work, for example:

```
public class Foo<Bar> {
    public Bar newBar(Class<Bar> prototype) {
        return GWT.create(prototype);
    }
}
```

where I would for example do `new Foo<MyBar>().newBar(MyBar.class)`?

But, ideally, I wouldn't even need to pass the prototype object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, no. The `GWT.create` method must always be called with an actual class literal, never with a variable/field/parameter. This is because `GWT.create` is actually a special sort of `new` with no arguments, and that won't work with a variable either (without reflection):

```
Class<? extends Bar> clazz = ...;
Bar instance = new clazz;//nope
```

The method `GWT.create` *looks* like a method call, and in Java it really is, but when you compile to JS, it must turn into a constructor call, following the specific deferred binding rules of the given permutation.

Comment: It's too bad that GWT.create(Bar) doesn't just work. It's not correct Java syntax and due to type-erasure, that construct wouldn't even make sense in regular Java, but the GWT compiler could have all info available that it needs to be smart enough to correctly implement this. But I guess this is quite the fringe use case anyways... Let me leave your answer unchecked for a couple of days, though, just in case someone has a good idea for another way to achieve the same thing...

Comment: Next time lead with what you are trying to do, not how you are trying to do it ;). The best way to achieve magic like that is still GWT.create, but at a different point in the code, and have a generator do the work for you of implementing `newBar` with the type details it has. Consider the UiBinder and various Editor driver types - you extend an interface, add generic args, GWT.create the result, and the generator uses the generic args to do the rest. Too long for a comment to show how to do it, but might be worth a try for you.

Comment: Note: don't leave off how you are trying to do it, but lead with the problem, not the broken solution. Knowing what you have tried makes it easier to suggest how to either fix it, or another approach to attempt.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. I guess the question title was supposed to be that lead... :) The first code segment was just an attempt to provide a shortest possible example of such an object creation...